# Can we have zero as a netlink multicast group id?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, netlink

The genl_bind() fails, I am using linux kernel 4.12. In this code, I see that the condition is never met -

```
 if (group >= f->mcgrp_offset &&
            group < f->mcgrp_offset + f->n_mcgrps)
```

Also, the ->mcast_bind function pointer is always zero. I am not sure what am I missing here. I see the group is 1 being passed. My question is for multicast netlink can we have zero as a multicast group id. I am unsure what am I missing here. My kernel space code has a mcast group of zero and user space application has a nl.group = 0xffff. Is this a problem? Should we have only non-zero group id? Why do I get binding error if there is a problem here. What group id number I should use which isn't reserved by Kernel?

```
static int genl_bind(struct net *net, int group)
{
    struct genl_family *f;
    int err = -ENOENT;
    unsigned int id;

    down_read(&cb_lock);

    idr_for_each_entry(&genl_fam_idr, f, id) {
        if (group >= f->mcgrp_offset &&
            group < f->mcgrp_offset + f->n_mcgrps) {
            int fam_grp = group - f->mcgrp_offset;

            if (!f->netnsok && net != &init_net)
                err = -ENOENT;
            else if (f->mcast_bind)
                err = f->mcast_bind(net, fam_grp);
            else
                err = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    up_read(&cb_lock);

    return err;
}
```

Comment: Requesting **off-site** documents is **off-topic** on Stack Overflow.